# android remoteView layout is not working

Tags: android

Been working all morning trying to place
the progressbar under the text "simulation in progress".
Can anyone give me help me?
Adding picture:[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:padding="3dp"
          >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
          />
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="#000"
          /> 
<ProgressBar
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
          android:id="@+id/status_progress"
          android:max="100"
          />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option, if you don't want to use a RelativeLayout, as suggested by other answer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:padding="3dp"
          >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
          />
<LinearLayout 
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="3dp"
          >
      <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="#000"
          /> 
      <ProgressBar
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
          android:id="@+id/status_progress"
          android:max="100"
          />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Adinia , wrapping LinearLayout like that is grate.
Im happy thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:padding="3dp"
          >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
          />
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="#000"
          android:layout_below="@+id/image"/> 
<ProgressBar
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
          android:id="@+id/status_progress"
          android:max="100"
          />
          </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just giving you an idea to use RelativeLayout properties.

Comment: But android:layout_below property should be used in the ProgressBar, to place it under TextView, as I understand from the question.

Comment: yes layout_below did the trick thank you Adinia.
but now the icon is behind the progressbar and the text.
Will do some tweeking

Comment: @user538837 in progressBar the line should be android:layout_below="@id/text"; also, you should set them to be at the right of the image; I was just pointing Aizaz that his answer is not complet. Again, you can try my other solution, too.